# Twitch API returning "Warning: Illegal string offset"

Tags: php

This code is supposed to get All featured channels on twitch, with their display name and live viewers, but it returns with "Warning: Illegal string offset 'channel' in ....

```
            <?php
            $hue = file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/featured');

            $hue1 = json_decode($hue, TRUE);

             foreach ($hue1 as $data)
                {
                 foreach ($data as $datas) {

                echo ($datas['channel']['display_name']."<br/>" .$datas['channel']['viewers']."");

                     }   
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: What does a single entry of the $datas array look like?

Comment: The $datas is such as the Display_name and viewers and so on.

Comment: Did you look at the JSON? There´s no `channel.viewers` key anywhere. There's `stream.viewers` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an associative array whose first two keys are _links and featured. You presumably want the featured array. Try this:

**EDITED VERSION**

```
<?php
$hue = file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/featured');
$api_values = json_decode($hue, TRUE, 8);

foreach ($api_values["featured"] as $entry){
         echo $entry['stream']['channel']['display_name'] . "<br/>" . $entry['stream']['viewers'];   
}
?>
```

When iterating over an associative array you know the shape of, it is useful to use the keys that you know exist.

Comment: You wouldnt mind posting all of it? with it working on your side, because on mine it displays "Warning: Illegal string offset 'featured' in /home2/thomasrb/public_html/twitch/index.php on line 75

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home2/thomasrb/public_html/twitch/index.php on line 75"

Comment: Sorry, I used $hue instead of $hue1. I edited the code.

Comment: You removed a line of your own code, and you are also not using my edited code. I will edit again to have everything you need to have a working example. Make sure you are using it.

Comment: That should be valid. Can you show the code that you are using again?

Comment: I've added a depth parameter to the json_decode. This might help, but I am just guessing.

Comment: So, I looked at my code carefully, and I feel like a fool. Here is a working example. I tested it a few times, and I am completely sure it does what you want.